# GRAPHQL mutation with axios

Tags: graphql, axios

Im using graphCMS and I want to make a post request using axios.

I can actually do a mutation in postman.
see example: https://prnt.sc/sjsj3p

but when in actual coding using axios, I cant get the proper format of the query.
I search some graphql mutation but it seems that the graphcms has a different format(Im not sure).

```
axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': graphcmsBearerKey
            },
            data: {
                query: `
                    mutation CreateCompanyCustomization() {
                        createCompanyCustomization(
                            data: {
                                domain: "sampledomain.com"
                            }
                        )
                    }
                `
            } 
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            isErrorState('ERROR STATE')
            console.log(err)
        })
```

any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: bad format - start with the same query shape

Comment: just copy query from postman?

Comment: yes, actually thats the actual query from postman. inside the data{}

Comment: EXACT copy ? .....